# Nodemailer send base64 data URI as attachment. How?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Basically I have an image created using Canvas and it's in base64 encoded data URI. This data URI is then attached to email.

```
...,
 attachments:[{
 filename: "cat.jpg",
 contents: new Buffer(cat, 'base64')
}],
```

The email is received but the attachment is not viewable. Running `$ file cat.jpg` in linux returns:

```
cat.jpg: ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```

Why is this ASCII? I had already mentioned base64. How may I fix this problem? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variable `cat` probably includes the *'data:image/jpeg;base64,'* part. You shouldn't pass that bit to `Buffer.from`.

It seems that if you pass in invalid data, `Buffer.from()` doesn't complain:

```
var pixel = "data:image/gif;base64,"
    + "R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACH5"
    + "BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==";
var buffer = Buffer.from(pixel, "base64"); // does not throw an error.
```

You even get back a valid Buffer. The buffer is a corrupt image (or rather, it doesn't begin with an image header).

You have to strip the first part of the data URI yourself:

```
var buffer = Buffer.from(pixel.split("base64,")[1], "base64");
```

---

Edit (may 2021): Changed `new Buffer` to `Buffer.from`, as the former is deprecated.

Comment: It works now. I'm just curious, did you know this or you tested it?

Comment: Not sure if I'm interpreting your question correctly, but: I *know* Nodemailer wants a valid image buffer and I *tested* that `new Buffer(stringWithPrefix)` creates a broken image and `new Buffer(stringWithoutPrefix)` does not. I could see that the constructor doesn't cause an error and that the two buffers don't start with the same bytes (as expected). Wrote the files to disk and checked their integrity. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 17):

A buffer is not needed. You can just put the string starting from behind the base64 encoding prefix into it:

```
var cat = "...base64 encoded image...";
var mailOptions = {
  ...
  attachments: [
    {   // encoded string as an attachment
      filename: 'cat.jpg',
      content: cat.split("base64,")[1],
      encoding: 'base64'
    }
  ]
};
```

More Details you find here: https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer#attachments

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `path` for that without any additional manipulations:

```
    let attachments = [
        {
            filename: "image.gif",
            path: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
        }
    ]
```

Here the link to the related [documentation](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/)

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: 100% accurate. Thank you - this took me a good day to figure out. For base64: use the `encoding: "base64" ` property as well
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the package `nodemailer-base64-to-s3`.

Install the package:

```
npm install -s nodemailer-base64-to-s3
```

Configure it with nodemailer:

```
var base64ToS3 = require('nodemailer-base64-to-s3');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({});
transport.use('compile', base64ToS3(opts));
```

https://github.com/ladjs/nodemailer-base64-to-s3