# Use Mailgun to send a pdf attachment from Base64 string

Tags: javascript, meteor, base64, email-attachments, mailgun

I have a pdf that is being generated by another function, which returns a Base64 string. I would like to then attach it to a Mailgun email [as attachment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js), which is [built into Meteor](https://docs.meteor.com/api/email.html) and [Mailgun](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#sending). I see that there is a lot of examples of attaching a file from the [file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963914/mailgun-send-mail-with-attachment), but I don't see anything using Base64.

I have a method that generates a Base64 string and concatonates with prefix in order to [convert Base64 to PDF](http://%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299799/how-to-open-base64-encoded-pdf-in-javascript/31319795):

```
//returns base64 string: looks like "YW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZQ=="
const base64AttachmentString = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + generatePdfBase64();

import { Email } from "meteor/email";

Email.send({
  to: "email@example.com",
  from: "John Smith <johnsmith@example.com>",
  subject: "Sending Base64 as PDF",
  html: generatedHTMLTemplate,
  attachment: base64AttachmentString
});
```

Is there a way to send a Base64 attachment where Mailgun will recognize it as a PDF? I know this is possible with other mailers such as [Nodemailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165410/nodemailer-send-base64-data-uri-as-attachment-how) and [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like meteor's Email requires you to add the `attachments` keys, which should be an array of attachments.

As for the options for the attachments - [there are multiple](https://github.com/nodemailer/mailcomposer/blob/v4.0.1/README.md#attachments):

```
    {   // utf-8 string as an attachment
        filename: 'text1.txt',
        content: 'hello world!'
    },
    {   // binary buffer as an attachment
        filename: 'text2.txt',
        content: new Buffer('hello world!','utf-8')
    },
    {   // file on disk as an attachment
        filename: 'text3.txt',
        path: '/path/to/file.txt' // stream this file
    },
    {   // filename and content type is derived from path
        path: '/path/to/file.txt'
    },
    {   // stream as an attachment
        filename: 'text4.txt',
        content: fs.createReadStream('file.txt')
    },
    {   // define custom content type for the attachment
        filename: 'text.bin',
        content: 'hello world!',
        contentType: 'text/plain'
    },
    {   // use URL as an attachment
        filename: 'license.txt',
        path: 'https://raw.github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/master/LICENSE'
    },
    {   // encoded string as an attachment
        filename: 'text1.txt',
        content: 'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQh',
        encoding: 'base64'
    },
    {   // data uri as an attachment
        path: 'data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='
    }
```

Specifically in your example you can use:

```
const base64AttachmentString = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + generatePdfBase64();

import { Email } from "meteor/email";

Email.send({
  to: "email@example.com",
  from: "John Smith <johnsmith@example.com>",
  subject: "Sending Base64 as PDF",
  html: generatedHTMLTemplate,
  attachments: [
    {
      path: base64AttachmentString
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Would I need to include any multipart/form-data encoding when sending attachment?

Comment: Pretty sure that you don't need that. Please check and update.

Comment: It's not working as is - just sending with no attachment. The string is logging, however.

Comment: @maudulus, doubled check - see the update in the answer

Comment: Tried and got: `TypeError: Path must be a string. Received <Buffer ...`. Also tried passing the base64 string but got: `Exception while invoking method 'saveClaim' { Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open '`. I think it might be expecting a file path

Comment: If you want to use the Buffer (from my previous example) you should use `content` and not `path`.